# Is there a "ContainsType" class?

Tags: haskell, types

I recently generalized a type class away from a constraint `MonadError GenError m` to a more flexible constraint of `MonadError e m, CanContainGenError e`.  This is useful for using the relevant monad transformer with a stack that already has an `ErrorT SomeError m` - I can just add `GenError` as an element of a new constructor in the `SomeError` data type.

I found myself surprised to be writing a custom `CanContainGenError` class hard-coded to `GenError`.  Isn't there a common `ContainedType` class or some such? (I almost called it "subtype", heh)

Anything like the below `CanContainType` or `ContainsType` classes I just made up?

```
class CanContainType cont orig where
    toCont   :: orig -> cont
    fromCont :: cont -> Maybe orig

class ContainsType orig sub where
    toContainer :: orig -> cont
    fromContainer :: cont -> orig
```

Where an example instantiation is:

```
-- edit fixed example instance to reflect what I want, sorry for the misleading code
data IntOrFloatOrDouble= I Int | F Float | D Double
instance CanContainType IntOrFloatOrDouble Int where
    toCont   = I
    fromCont (I a) = Just a
    fromCont _ = Nothing
```

Now that I've typed this out I'm realizing there probably isn't an established one because my requirements mandate MPTCs.  Still, I'm interested in any thoughts.

Comment: Your `toCont` for IntAndStuff doesn't work. Which also point to why your `toCont` and `toContainer` functions are a bit poorly typed, I think. If you inject a value into a container, you need default values for all the other bits. Generally, I think this solution is a bit too inbetween and weak, so folks who want/need this frequently step up to HList based solutions.

Comment: @sclv Right ,that instance was poorly thought out.  In my real code I have `data SomeError = PreExistinErr1 | PreExistinErr2 | IsGenError GenError` and in the instance it's just `toCont = IsGenError`.  This is why I don't need default bits.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things like this come up in EDSL construction, for lifting instances from Haskell to the EDSL. See e.g. http://www.galois.com/~dons/tmp/Type.hs

```
data IntegralType a where
  TypeInt     :: IntegralDict Int     -> IntegralType Int
  TypeInt8    :: IntegralDict Int8    -> IntegralType Int8
  TypeInt16   :: IntegralDict Int16   -> IntegralType Int16
  TypeInt32   :: IntegralDict Int32   -> IntegralType Int32
  TypeInt64   :: IntegralDict Int64   -> IntegralType Int64
  ...
```

There's nothing standard, obviously.